# Set of lines to replace in file - python

Tags: python, replace, updates, lines

I am new to python. I am trying to use a file with new data (newprops) to replace the old data on a second file. Both files are over 3MB.

File with new data looks like this:

```
PROD    850 30003   0.096043  
PROD    851 30003   0.096043  
PROD    853 30003   0.096043  
PROD    852 30003   0.096043  
....
```

Original file with old data is something like:

```
CROD    850     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    850     30003   0.08  
CROD    851     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    851     30003   0.07  
CROD    852     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    852     30003   0.095  
CROD    853     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    853     30003   0.095  
....
```

Output should be:

```
CROD    850     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    850     30003   0.096043  
CROD    851     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    851     30003   0.096043  
CROD    852     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    852     30003   0.096043  
CROD    853     123456 123457 123458 123459  
PROD    853     30003   0.096043
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
import fileinput

def prop_update(newprops,bdffile):

    fnewprops=open(newprops,'r')
    fbdf=open(bdffile,'r+')
    newpropsline=fnewprops.readline()
    fbdfline=fbdf.readline()


    while len(newpropsline)>0:
        fbdf.seek(0)
        propname=newpropsline.split()[1]
        propID=newpropsline.split()[2]
            while len(fbdfline)>0:
                if propID and propname in fbdfline:
                    bdffile.write(newpropsline) #i'm stuck here... I want to delete the old line and use updated value                   
                else:                    
                    fbdfline=fbdfline.readline()

        newpropsline=fnewprops.readline()

    fnewprops.close()
```

Please help!

Comment: It would help if you let us know which block of data is `newprops` and which block of data is `bdffile` to better assist you.

Comment: newprops is the block on top, bdffile is the second exerpt. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict to index the new data. Then write the original file to a new file, line by line, updating data from the index as you go. It looks like the first three items should be the key ("PROD    850 30003") and they can be pulled out with a regex such as `(PROD\s+\d+\s+\d+)`.

```
import re
_split_new = re.compile(r"(PROD\s+\d+\s+\d+)(.*)")

# create an index for the PROD items to be updated

# this might be a bit more understandable...
#with open('updates.txt') as updates:
#    new_data = {}
#    for line in updates:
#        match = _split_new.match(line)
#        if match:
#            key, value = match.groups()
#            new_data[key] = value

# ... but this is fancier (and likely faster)
with open('updates.txt') as updates:
    new_data = dict(match.groups() 
        for match in (_split_new.search(line) for line in updates)
        if match)

# then process the updates
with open('origstuff.txt') as orig, open('newstuff.txt', 'w') as newstuff:
    # for each line in the original...
    for line in orig:
        match = _split_new.match(line)
        # ... see if its a PROD line
        if match:
            key, value = match.groups()
            # ... and rewrite with value from indexing dict (defaulting to current value)
            newstuff.write("%s%s\n" % (key, new_data.get(key, value)))
        else:
            # ... or just the original line
            newstuff.write(line)
```

Comment: awesome this is exactly what I needed! thank you for help and for the layman explanations in the code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take every second line from the original and zip them with the new lines then reopen the original and write the updated lines, presuming the new lines are equal to half the length or the original:

```
from itertools import izip

with open("new.txt") as f,open("orig.txt") as f2:
    lines = f2.readlines()
    zipped = izip(lines[::2],f) # just use zip for python3
    with open("orig.txt","w") as out:
        for pair in zipped:
            out.writelines(pair)
```

If you want the lines sorted based on the second column, you also need to strip and insert newlines manually so the final lines get separated:

```
from itertools import izip,islice

with open("new.txt") as f, open("orig.txt") as f2:
    orig = sorted((x.strip() for x in islice(f2, 0, None, 2)), key=lambda x: int(x.split(None, 2)[1]))
    new = sorted((x.strip() for x in f), key=lambda x:int(x.split(None,2)[1]))
    zipped = izip(orig, new)
    with open("orig.txt","w") as out:
        for pair in zipped:
            out.write("{}\n{}\n".format(*pair))
```

Output:

```
CROD 850 123456 123457 123458 123459
PROD 850 30003 0.096043
CROD 851 123456 123457 123458 123459
PROD 851 30003 0.096043
CROD 852 123456 123457 123458 123459
PROD 852 30003 0.096043
CROD 853 123456 123457 123458 123459
PROD 853 30003 0.096043
```

if the length is not the same you can use [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with a fillvalue of `""` so you don't lose any data:

If the old file is already in order just forget the sorted call on f2 and use `f2.readlines()[::2]` but if it is not in order then this will make sure all lines are sorted based on the second column regardless of the original order.

Comment: This does assume that the lines are properly ordered and not missing numbers... From the data provided it seems like 853 might come before 852...

Comment: @aychedee, if that is the case the lines will have to be sorted by the second word which is not hard to do

Comment: could limit memory consumption by building a custom generator [like so](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/2fc47c411aa5a71e0748). If `orig.txt` is too big, this could be scary :)

Comment: @AdamSmith, true but the OP's fies are not very big, memory won't be an issue so no scary moments. :) OP said the are around 3MB

Comment: wow, was not familiar with itertools, very helpful. The original also contains lots of other values of data at the top and at the bottom of the exerpt and might be anywhere in the file so getting the second line won't necessarily be true(it is a nastran bdf file, if you are familiar with it).